# nginx as proxy to my mysql server in docker

Tags: mysql, nginx, proxy, docker

I'm working with a server in the cloud with N dockers containers, in the server I have one nginx that redirect based on the domain to my docker containers, I can perfectly redirect my http traffic, but I'm getting troubles with when it is mysql since it uses a protocol different to http, I tried some solutions like below but didn't work, can someone give me one light where is my mistake?

```
upstream mysql {
    server 127.0.0.1:1401;
}

server {

    listen       80;

    server_name  mydomain.com.br www.mydomain.com.br;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1400;
    }
}

server {

    listen 3306;

    server_name mydomain.com.br www.mydomain.com.br;

    location / {
        proxy_pass mysql;
    }
}
```

I already saw this page (https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/), but did not work when i try to define the server_name / domain:

```
 stream {
    server {
        listen 12345;
        proxy_pass example.com:12345;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use MaxScale for this. https://mariadb.com/de/products/mariadb-maxscale

Comment: thanks, but I really want to use nginx, just redirecting the flow

Answer (score 2):

i just figure out that is not possible with other protocols to handle dns names, ill just use port redirection provided by docker